# Is there anyway I could stop my loop looping

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

When I try to insert the correct pass which is 1234 "Access Granted".
However, when I try to insert it after multiple attempts it will output "Access Denied" which should not.

```
import java.util.*;

class access {
    void granted () {
        System.out.println("Access Granted!"); 
    }

    void denied() {
        System.out.println("Access Denied!");
        System.out.println("Please try again! Re-enter your passcode: ");
    }

    void ct1 () {
        System.out.println("System is disabling now due to multiple attempts made");
    }
}

class passEnter extends Passcode {
    void Enter1 () {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        super.pass = sc.nextInt();
    }
}

public class Passcode {

    static int code = 1234;
    static int pass;

    public static void main (String [] agrs) {

        access access = new access();
        passEnter reEnter = new passEnter();
        int ct = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter your passcode ");
        reEnter.Enter1();

        // This is where my problem begins...
        if (pass != code) {
            while (ct < 2) {
                ct++;
                access.denied();
                reEnter.Enter1();
            } 
            access.ct1();
        } 
        else {
            access.granted();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To stop executing a loop, use the "break" command

Comment: I tried BREAK; but it will output the method access.ct1(); which should not be.

Comment: `access.ct1()` is outside the `while` loop. So it will be executed after breaking from `while` loop.

Comment: I'm agree with @PrasadKarunagoda

Comment: BREAK is use in Breaking and jump out of loop and will print whatever outside the loop.

Comment: so i tried to reverse the code since I cannot use break or continue.. I nested IF to WHILE statement instead; However, still not working  ELSE { access.granted();}is not executing access.denied(); still. Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you enter a wrong password once, you enter your while loop. You ask for the next entry inside this loop. The loop therefore gets repeated. This is why you can never enter the the else block in which you say granted, after entering a wrong password once.

Comment: so  okay, I tried to reverse the code to IF STATEMENT nested to WHILE loop; however this time, ELSE { access.granted();}is not  executing still access denied.

Comment: Here's my code:                                                                                              while (ct < 2) {
 if (pass !=code) {
 ct++;
 access.denied();
 reEnter.Enter1();
 } else {
 access.granted();
 }
 } access.ct1();

Comment: Just use the if statement and check the value of the counter. Don't use while at all.

Comment: if I am only going to use IF statement and I wanted my program to ask to re-enter passcode for 3 times in case wrong passcode is entered then I will nested IF to IF statement?

Comment: Yes i'm sorry. That was an oversight on my part. What you want to do is use break; to exit your while loop when a correct password is detected.

Comment: I don't think I can use BREAK; because lets say I entered Incorrect password 3x hence counter will ++..then it will jump out  of while loop since ct > 3 now and output "Access Granted" which shouldn't.

Comment: Heres the code: while (ct < 2) { 
    if (pass !=code  || ct > 3 ) { 
        ct++; 
        access.denied(); 
        reEnter.Enter1(); }
    else{ 
        break;
    } 
} access.granted();

Comment: You should check for correct input inside the while loop. If correct input is detected, break out of it.